# Extract First and Last character vectors from a column that is a list: R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having difficulties implementing a solution for this question provided by users on many similar questions like this. See sample df below.

```r
structure(list(FirstName = c("Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore", 
"Harry James Potter", "Tom Marvollo Riddle", "Lord Voldemort"
), Email = c("albusD@hogwarts.com", "harryP@hogwarts.com", "tomR@hogwarts.com", 
"LV@Wiz.com"), ClassSection = c("HeadMaster", "Student", "Dark Lord in training", 
"Dark Lord")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(FirstName = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Email = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ClassSection = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to create a new column, where the first and last names are united. For this,
I first tried `separate(FirstName, sep = " ", into("First", "Middle", Last")`. However, what happens is that there are other word elements that get missed. So, I'm not able to effectively combine them together.

Next, I tried, `df%>% mutate(First = str_split(FirstName, pattern = " "))`. This gives a list of elements. I want a way to extract the first and the last element from this column.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  FirstName                               Email               ClassSection          First    
  <chr>                                   <chr>               <chr>                 <list>   
1 Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore albusD@hogwarts.com HeadMaster            <chr [4]>
2 Harry James Potter                      harryP@hogwarts.com Student               <chr [3]>
3 Tom Marvollo Riddle                     tomR@hogwarts.com   Dark Lord in training <chr [3]>
4 Lord Voldemort                          LV@Wiz.com          Dark Lord             <chr [2]>
```

I looked at various answers where `tail(First, n=1)` and dplyr's `last(First)` was suggested. However, these don't give me the right answer. I also tried `unnest_wider(First)` but it has the same problem as `separate(firstName)`. That is, I see multiple columns. Now these don't work for names that are just two or more than 3 words.

I'm looking to continue the dplyr (tidyverse's) workflow. Is there a way I can get the first and last vector to combine together into a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    FirstLast = sapply(str_split(FirstName, pattern = " "),
                       \(z) paste(z[unique(c(1, length(z)))], collapse = ""))
  )
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   FirstName                               Email               ClassSection          FirstLast      
#   <chr>                                   <chr>               <chr>                 <chr>          
# 1 Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore albusD@hogwarts.com HeadMaster            AlbusDumbledore
# 2 Harry James Potter                      harryP@hogwarts.com Student               HarryPotter    
# 3 Tom Marvollo Riddle                     tomR@hogwarts.com   Dark Lord in training TomRiddle      
# 4 Lord Voldemort                          LV@Wiz.com          Dark Lord             LordVoldemort
```

or much more simply

```r
df %>%
  mutate(FirstLast = sub(" .* ", "", FirstName))
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   FirstName                               Email               ClassSection          FirstLast      
#   <chr>                                   <chr>               <chr>                 <chr>          
# 1 Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore albusD@hogwarts.com HeadMaster            AlbusDumbledore
# 2 Harry James Potter                      harryP@hogwarts.com Student               HarryPotter    
# 3 Tom Marvollo Riddle                     tomR@hogwarts.com   Dark Lord in training TomRiddle      
# 4 Lord Voldemort                          LV@Wiz.com          Dark Lord             Lord Voldemort
```

Comment: For me, Albus Percival is the first name (I just want Albus).

Comment: The question says *"I want to create a new column, where the first and last names are united"*. I'm working on the premise that "united" means the two are combined into a single string. What is your actual expected output?

Comment: Expected output would be (for FirstLast column): AlbusDumbledore (the first word and the last word) combined. Right now, it's Albus Percival Dumbledore.

Comment: Okay, I'll change my `collapse = " "` (with a space) to `collapse = ""` (no space), and the output here changes from `"Albus Dumbledore"` to `"AlbusDumbledore"`. Is that it?

Comment: I think there's a problem with my RStudio. Your output (and Akrun's) is Albus Dumbledore (for the first last column) but for me it includes the second word (i.e. Percival) .

Answer (score 2):

We may use `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, FirstName, into = c("First", "Last"),
    "^(\\S+)\\s*.*\\s+(\\S+)$", remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  FirstName                               First Last       Email               ClassSection         
  <chr>                                   <chr> <chr>      <chr>               <chr>                
1 Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore Albus Dumbledore albusD@hogwarts.com HeadMaster           
2 Harry James Potter                      Harry Potter     harryP@hogwarts.com Student              
3 Tom Marvollo Riddle                     Tom   Riddle     tomR@hogwarts.com   Dark Lord in training
4 Lord Voldemort                          Lord  Voldemort  LV@Wiz.com          Dark Lord
```

---

Or to extract from the `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df%>%
   mutate(First = str_split(FirstName, pattern = " "), .after = FirstName) %>% 
   mutate(First = map(First, ~ tibble(First = first(.x), 
       Last = last(.x)))) %>% 
   unnest_wider(First)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  FirstName                               First Last       Email               ClassSection         
  <chr>                                   <chr> <chr>      <chr>               <chr>                
1 Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore Albus Dumbledore albusD@hogwarts.com HeadMaster           
2 Harry James Potter                      Harry Potter     harryP@hogwarts.com Student              
3 Tom Marvollo Riddle                     Tom   Riddle     tomR@hogwarts.com   Dark Lord in training
4 Lord Voldemort                          Lord  Voldemort  LV@Wiz.com          Dark Lord
```

Comment: For me, I still see the name in first column as: Albus Percival (for both methods)

Comment: I think there's a problem with my Rstudio. I think the code you have mentioned is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Pss I was thinking that you need two columns based on your code